# Django DecimalField inconsistent rounding

Tags: python, django, postgresql, rounding, decimal-point

Django 2.2, PostgreSQL database. I have a `Line` object with a `positions` property. This is an `ArrayField` of a `DecimalField` with a `max_digits` of 12 and `decimal_places` of 3.

I store some floats as `Decimal`s and get them back out of the Database:

```py
pos = [6586.87849502, 2.04190477e-01, 7.14666669e-01]
line = Line(positions=pos)
line.save()
line.refresh_from_db()  # send it through Django's ORM piping
print(line.positions)
```

Output:

> [Decimal('6586.87**9**'), Decimal('0.204'), Decimal('0.715')]

Interestingly, the first position was rounded up despite its next more significant digit being below 5. The other float is rounded down as expected.

I thought it might be PostgreSQL messing around, but no:

```sql
INSERT INTO line(positions) VALUES (array[6586.87849502, 2.04190477e-01, 7.14666669e-01]) RETURNING positions;
```

> positions (numeric[])
> {6586.878,0.204,0.715}

The real issue is that I'm trying to predict what will come out of the database, down to the required precision of three decimal places:

```py
[Decimal(x).quantize(Decimal("0.001")) for x in pos]
```

might yield

> [Decimal('6586.878'), Decimal('0.204'), Decimal('0.715')]

or

> [Decimal('6586.879'), Decimal('0.205'), Decimal('0.714')]

depending on the `decimal.ROUND_*` flag I pass in `quantize()`, but I never get consistent rounding throughout the array. What kind of pre-processing does Django do to my numbers before inserting them?